# Performance/Best Practice: If statement in for loop or for loop in if statement

Tags: javascript, performance

In the interest of writing neat and fast code I ran into a question and with some searching didn't find the answer. What's the best practice for writing code in this situation?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < message.timesheets.length; i++) {
  if (message.timesheets.length > 1) {
    // Run function
  } else {
    // Run other function
  }
};
```

OR

```js
if (message.timesheets.length > 1) {
  for(let i = 0; i < message.timesheets.length; i++) {
    // Run function
  };
} else {
  for(let i = 0; i < message.timesheets.length; i++) {
    // Run other function
  };
}
```

My thoughts is that the first option is easier to read but less preformant because it has to evaluate the if each time the for loop loops. The second option only has to run the function contained each time the for loop loops but is harder to read and is longer. The question that arises as both these snippets do the same with is which way of doing it is better? If one is not necessarily better than the other which one is faster?

EDIT: What you guys don't understand is that I didn't copy my entire project into the question. For the sake of the question we assume the message.timesheets array can have values equalling one (1) and more than one (1).

Comment: `if (message.timesheets.length > 1) {` this line is useless

Comment: The if statement determines which version of a notification a user will see depending on how many items need to be communicated ("Timesheet approved: [hours] approved on [date]" vs "13 Timesheets approved: see more..."). It has a use in the project I'm working on. How's it useless?

Comment: OP is correct, it's not useless, because it's checking if the value is greater than 1, not 0.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime is correct.  So if your timesheet count does not depend on the `for` loop results, you should run the `if` only once, outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-evaluating the same `if` condition in the loop over and over is indeed slower. However, this would not matter unless your array way *really* huge, and instead you should focus on writing clean and readable code instead.

You probably can (and should) simplify to

```
const run = message.timesheets.length > 1 ? oneFunction : otherFunction;
for (const timesheet of message.timesheets)
  run(timesheet);
```

which is both dry and fast.

Comment: That's amazingly clean code! I didn't know javascript had a java-esque shorthand if ? operator.

Comment: @MicahFriesen I don't think there's any modern language not having the [conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (there are however some that don't have `if` statements :P)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the second option, since it will perform only one test operation and then enter a loop, while the first one will enter into a loop and it will perform a test operation at every iteration.

It can be seen as:

```
Loop
  |_Test
       |_ do
  |_Test
       |_ do
  |_Test
       |_ do
  |_Test
       |_ do
End
```

and:

```
Test
   |_ Loop
      |_ do
      |_ do
      |_ do
      |_ do
   |_ End
```

Respectively. I'm not an expert on this, it's just my opinion, it also depends on how the JS interpreter (or compiler) handles this situations, there might be some optimizations that make the first option the best (or worst). If you want to be sure, you can take a look into a JS engine code, like the Google's V8 JS engine

Answer (score 1):

Since the second for loop (in the second example) only runs for 1 iteration if the conditional is false, you can leave out the second loop.

```
if (message.timesheets.length > 1) {
  for(let i = 0; i < message.timesheets.length; i++) {
    // Run function
  };
} else if (message.timesheets.length == 1) {
  let i=0;
  // Run other function
}
```

Thanks to Bergi for pointing out that the else statement should be an else if, in case length is 1.

Comment: 1 or 0 iterations. You still need at least an `if` statement. Otherwise I'd agree.

Comment: Geniuses catching these things like that. Well thought through.

Answer (score 0):

Since your test (the size of the array) is known before having to loop, you don't need to leave it till the last moment. And as bergi points out, use the test to choose the function to call in one single loop.

Basically, this comes down to premature optimisation. This really shouldn't matter. Write your code to be readable first, then in the future, if you have performance problems, investigate why. I bet you this will never be a problem.

> [Premature optimisation](https://medium.com/@dnrvs/premature-optimisation-d9940768a75f), in programming, is the act of optimising a piece of code before we know that we need to. It’s an important problem to spot because it’s often a waste of time; there are other tasks to do and what appears to be a problem at the micro level might only be a fraction of the entire system. You can’t tell what’s important without taking a step back to analyse the whole

Comment: However it's still an educational question to ask imo. Look how much I've learned from asking it. When you've got nothing to do at midnight it's worthwhile.